valgrind tests failed in speller cs50?
My code failed valgring test.I tried so many times to figure out the error and I gave up.can someone help me to find the error ..
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>

#include "dictionary.h"

//gloabal variables;

unsigned int word_count;
unsigned int hash_num;

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//setting hash table to null

//for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
//{
   // table[i] = NULL;
//}

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    //hashing the word

    hash_num = hash(word);

    node* cursor = table[hash_num];

    while(cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    // TODO: Improve this hash function
    //return toupper(word[0]) - 'A';
    unsigned long total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        total+=tolower(word[i]);
    }

    return total % N;


}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open the dictionary file
    FILE *source = fopen(dictionary,"r");

    if(source == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open the file\n");
        return false;
    }

    //Read each words in the file

    char current_word[LENGTH+1];

    while (fscanf(source, "%s", current_word) != EOF)
    {

        node *current_wrd = malloc(sizeof(node));

        if(current_wrd == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        //copy the word to node

        strcpy(current_wrd->word, current_word); //cant equate 2 strings.have to use strcpy;
        hash_num = hash(current_word);

        current_wrd->next = table[hash_num]; //current_wrd is a ptr.it's next field is ALSE a ptr.
                                             //next should set to what table is currently pointing

        table[hash_num] = current_wrd; //now you can store the current_wrd memory address in table
        //hash table is array oh Heads in linked lists
        word_count++;
    }

    fclose(source);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    if(word_count > 0)
    {
        return word_count;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];


        while(cursor)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }

        if(cursor == NULL)
        {
            free(cursor);
            return true;
        }
    }
    //free(cursor);
    return false;
}


Here is the log with the error message. It says it's coming from line 96:
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpx3faci2p -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1: (file: dictionary.c, line: 96) 

hear is my line 96
node *current_wrd = malloc(sizeof(node));
I tried so many times to figure out the error and gave up. from where the memory leak is happening ?

Run it yourself in Valgrind to see the full leak error message.

Why don't you initialize table with NULL-pointers at the beginning of load? What is the purpose of free(cursor) if cursor == NULL in unload? It is recommended to add a minimal reproducible example to your question. Please share full valgrind output.

I did a bit of refactoring of your code just to get it to compile and load a simple list of letters from a text file.  First off, I would suggest you avoid global variables and such as it makes tracing code hard.  But the one thing I noted when doing some simple debugging was that the node table was being loaded with pointer values after an attempt was being made to store the table values in the "current_wrd->next" pointer value.  So that value was always NULL.  So when the unload function was called, only the first "cursor" node pointer value was freed and subsequent nodes were not freed.
